# How can I check if the string contains certain word?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a series looks like this:

```
0          1.5 
1      39 mins 
2          2.5 
3            3
```

And I want to convert 39 mins to 0.39. And the following is my code:

```
df['content_duration'].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('mins', '').astype(int) * 1/100 if x in 'mins' else x)
```

I do not get an error, but it still won't convert it. How can I make this possible?
My expected output would be:

```
0          1.5 
1         0.39
2          2.5 
3            3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
# dataset for read_clipboard()
'''
content_duration
1.5 
39 mins 
2.5 
3 
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard('\t')

df['content_duration'] = df['content_duration'].apply(lambda x: int(x.replace('mins', '').strip()) * 1/100 if 'mins' in x else x)


print(df)
```

Output:

```
  content_duration
0             1.5 
1             0.39
2             2.5 
3                3
```

Comment: I modified my response. Please check the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.loc` and `str.extract`

```
df.loc[df[0].str.contains('mins'),0]  = df[0].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)[0] / 100

print(df)

      0
0   1.5
1  0.39
2   2.5
3     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative slightly longer;

```
df2=df[df['content_duration'].str.contains('mins', na=False)]#mask mins and extract new df
df2['content_duration']=(df2['content_duration'].str.strip('mins').astype(int)/100).astype(str)#Transform mins
df.update(df2)#Updatedf
```

[image: df]